# iOS UITextField Underline Style in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image: UI Interface Login example]

I've added this image, I hope you can see it, of a user interface login. Notice the text field is transparent with the exception of the line at the bottom. What code do I put in to get that affect? Can I put the necessary information in the "user defined runtime attributes"?

Comment: Just use a image as the background, the image contains a line at the bottom, and the above is transparent.  This kind of image will fit your demand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image: Your output]

Create a subclass of `UITextField` as below, And simply set this class in your storyboard to `UITextField`

**Swift 5 Support With @IBInspectable**

```
import UIKit

class HSUnderLineTextField: UITextField , UITextFieldDelegate {

    let border = CALayer()

    @IBInspectable open var lineColor : UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet{
            border.borderColor = lineColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable open var selectedLineColor : UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet{
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable open var lineHeight : CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0) {
        didSet{
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - lineHeight, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: (NSCoder?)) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder!)
        self.delegate=self;
        border.borderColor = lineColor.cgColor
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder ?? "",
                                                               attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])


        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - lineHeight, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = lineHeight
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - lineHeight, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - lineHeight, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        border.borderColor = selectedLineColor.cgColor
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        border.borderColor = lineColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

[image]

Set `lineColor` and `selectedLineColor` from the storyboard and run your project.

Comment: Rather than making whole `class`, why don't you make `extension`?

Comment: If i have create class then no need to write any code, simply we can use in storyboard file And i have create extension then we need to write code in view-controller class where we use text field.

Comment: Let me get this strait. I'm suppose to create a custom cocoa class that's named UItextField and is a subclass of UItextField?

Comment: Name of this class is not  UItextField but it is subclass of  UItextField. You can give a any name of this class like UITextField_BottomBorder then set it in your storyboard file

Comment: That worked almost perfectly. Thanks so much! Though I do have one request on this and that is changing the color so something of a hex value or an RGB value. How can I change "border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor" to be something with an RGB value or a hex value?

Comment: I tried putting this at the beginning with the let border and width commands:
let myDarkBlue = UIColor(red:32.0, green:53.0, blue:88.0, alpha:1.0)
Then I changed the code for the color to:
border.borderColor = myDarkBlue.CGColor
But it didn't work. Just turned the color of the line to white.

Comment: I tried putting in your code for the color:
    "border.borderColor = UIColor(red:32.0, green:53.0, blue:88.0, alpha:1.0)"
but it had an error message. "Cant assign UIColor to type CGColor"

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I am sure this time work for you.

Comment: @HiteshSurani Do you really need the repetition?
`self.layer.addSublayer(border)`
`self.layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: If anyone else is having issues with small vertical lines showing on the side of the textfield, I was able to fix it by setting all the heights to 1.0 instead of self.frame.size.height

Comment: Worked very well, thx! It would be nice if you'd use KVO to detect the focus, so the delegate can be freely used by the user of the class.