# iOS: Moving bottom border of UITextField down

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I added bottom border to UITextField this way:

```
let bottomLine = CALayer()
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.height, self.frame.width, CGFloat(borderWidth))
bottomLine.backgroundColor = borderColor.CGColor
self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

And I am getting this:

[image]

I would like move border down. To do this I am setting border frame this way:

```
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.height + 5, self.frame.width, CGFloat(borderWidth))
```

Here I am increasing it by 5px. But it moves beyond the text field's frame. But I cannot adjust `UITextField`'s height:

[image]

If I am setting it programmatically, application hangs on refreshing designables (I am using `IBDesignable` subclass of `UITextField`).

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303520/ios-uitextfield-border-style-in-swift/38303809#38303809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select show attribute inspector then change border style

see below image[image]